# How can i display each new image in pictureBox1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 i have a timer tick event where i save screenshots to the hard disk:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            sc.CaptureScreenToFile(mainDirectory + count.ToString("D6") + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            sc.CaptureScreen();
            label2.Text = count.ToString();
            if (count == 1)
            {
                label4.Text = string.Format("{0:N2} KB", GetFileSizeOnDisk(mainDirectory + "000001.jpg").ToString());
                label4.Visible = true;
            }           
        }
        DisplayImages();
```

Each time after a new screenshot is saved to the hard disk i want to display this image in pictureBox1.
And then the next after it...The timer interval set to 1000ms. So the screenshots in pictureBox1 should be change each a second.

```
private void DisplayImages()
        {

        }
```

How can i get each second the file on the hard disk and display it in the pictureBox ? And also to make sure that the file is not in use if it's important.

For example the first file on the hard  disk is: 000001.jpg then 000002.jpg and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      count++;
      string fileName = mainDirectory + count.ToString("D6") + ".jpg";
      sc.CaptureScreenToFile(fileName , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      sc.CaptureScreen();
      label2.Text = count.ToString();
      if (count == 1)
      {
          label4.Text = string.Format("{0:N2} KB", GetFileSizeOnDisk(fileName).ToString());
          label4.Visible = true;
      }    
      pictureBox1.ImageLocation =  fileName;   
}
```